# Error while adding controller in asp.net core Application VS2017

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I am working on Asp.net Core Application with Angular 2. There are few default controllers available when we create an application. When I tried to add a new controller, I am getting below error.

[image]

Comment: did you tried turning it off & on? try opening vs with admin rights just to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Please tag angular 2+ questions with angular, not angularjs.

Comment: @Sid No luck, still same error!